# how to tokenize indic languages using inltk

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, tokenize, transliteration

i did this using this NLP documentation check it out:
https://inltk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

```
from inltk.inltk import tokenize 
text="जो मुझको सताती है तुझे वो बातें आती है जब सामने तू होता नहीं बेचैनी बढ़ जाती है मैं रूठ "
tokenize(text ,'hi')
```

the error is:

```
RuntimeError: Internal: src/sentencepiece_processor.cc(890)
[model_proto->ParseFromArray(serialized.data(), serialized.size())]
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you encountered usually appears when a wrong SPM model is used, or when there is any other issue related to SPM model.

Make sure you set up the language support first:

```py
from inltk.inltk import setup
setup('hi')
```

Comment: yes i have done this ```from inltk.inltk import setup
setup('hi')``` ...i think the problem is the installation part```!pip install torch==1.3.1+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
!pip install inltk ``` the error is coming like this ..ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
torchvision 0.11.1+cu111 requires torch==1.10.0, but you have torch 1.3.1+cpu which is incompatible.

Comment: @hammish Right, you need to make sure you install it without issues.